# How can I update the message body using gmail API in javascript

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I have got the message body. Now I want to update it according to my needs. I am using this login/code. but it says 400 error. I think issue is in body parameter of the request. Would you please help me there?

```
var token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

var messageId = "18514426e2b99017";


        async function updateMessageBody() {
var updatedBody = "Hello,\n\nThis is the UPDATED message body.\n\nBest regards,\nJohn";
          const API_KEY = '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-CXIk';
          const headers = {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          };

          const response = await fetch(`https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/18514426e2b99017/modify?key=['API_KEY']`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({
              raw: window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(updatedBody)))
            })
          });

          if (!response.ok) {
            // throw new Error(`Request failed with status code ${response.status}`);
          }

          return await response.json();
        }

    updateMessageBody()
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Message body updated successfully:', response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
  });
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your detailed error from `but it says 400 error.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By the way, can I think that your access token can be used for updating the message of Gmail?

Comment: I just want to update the message body. How can I do this?
Yes, there is no issue with access token, it's working fine for other requests. But when I make this request, It says 400 error. I just wanna update the message body. Here is endpoint URL that I am using "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/18514426e2b99017/modify?key=[API KEY]"
can it be used to update message body?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot find the detailed error message from your reply. But, if you want to use [Method: users.messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify), in this case, only the labels can be modified while the message body cannot be modified. And also, I'm worried that the message body of the received message might not be able to be modified by an user.

Comment: It gives me this error message "message
: 
"Request failed with status code 404". 
Message body can be changed, but I don't why it is throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

Checking the documentation, it states that a message body can't be altered once it has been created, meaning that once you have already created an email this message can't be changed. You can verify this [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides).

[image]

You can instead update a `message draft` which is possibly what you are trying to do, however using the endpoint you have in your code this won't be possible and will lead to the error message you are getting, try using instead the [`users.draft.update`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/update) method that allows you to modify the content of the draft sitting in your mailbox. Please note as well that using the method [`users.messages`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages) does not have any `update` method as they only have the `modify` one's, those methods can only update the labels though so please be aware of that.

[image]